# How to first sort by FIELD and then other field ASC

Tags: php, sql

How to first sort by FIELD and then other filed ASC? I am working on an SQL query to list items dynamically with an ajax request "[here](https://justmoney.dk/billige-laan/)", however i have some troubles with getting the right order.

I wanna do something like this:

```
$variable = “6,7,8”;

SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > 5 ORDER BY FIELD(id, $variable), ranking ASC.
```

However my list gets sorted by ranking first and the the ids last. I want to get the selected id’s first and then other records by “ranking” below that.

Is that possible ?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the desired result - as well formatted text.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `FIELD()` returns `0` when there is no match.  I woudl recommend that you treat the value as a *string* (rather than stuffing the value in to the `IN` list) and use `find_in_set()`:

```
ORDER BY (FIND_IN_SET(id, $variable) > 0) DESC,
         ranking ASC
```

The `DESC` is so the "true" values (which are treated as "1") go before the "false" values ("0").

If you do care about the ordering in your list, then include another key:

```
ORDER BY (FIND_IN_SET(id, $variable) > 0) DESC,
         FIND_IN_SET(id, $variable),
         ranking ASC
```